# Five concerns about this short driving related text

Tags: word-meaning

> The cars that are going straight have the right of way. Which means we have to wait for them before we make our left turn. Where do you wait? The rule of thumb, if the light is green we want to wait up here in the intersection. As soon as this **line clears** and we have enough gap then we're able to execute our left turn safely. **The right of way rules for a right turn if we reverse it** . Let's say we're making a right turn into this roadway and there are cars that are coming from this direction that are making a left turn into the same roadway. The vehicle closer to the turn would have the right of way. Therefore the car to the right **gets to go** first **over the car** that's making the left into the same roadway. There's lots of different **variations** on turns these are some of the right of way rules. Hope that will help you with that and help you to pass your road test.

1. When it says **... as soon as this line clears** , what the word **line** is reffering to? Line on the road? Would a line on the road clear? A line on a traffic light? Does a traffic light have a line on itself? I am confused. And what does it mean when it **clears** ?
2. I cannot understand this part saying: **The right of way rules for a right turn if we reverse it** ... Is the word "rules" a verb here? A plural noun?
3. **Get to go** ? Does it mean **should go** ?
4. **Over** ? What does it mean?
5. What substitution would you use instead of "variations" in this text?

A million thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

**Re 1:** I'd say it's a "line of oncoming cars". If there are no more cars, or if someone stops to let you pass, the line gets "cleared" for you, i.e. there is a gap which you can use to turn left.

**Re 2:** Verb. In this case you have the "right of way", because you are the one who is on the "straight" line (see the very first sentence). Even if you want to turn right, this "right of way" rules.

**Re 3:** Something between "may go" and "has to go".

**Re 4:** "before". "Over" is kind of hierarchy.

**Re 5:** "variants"

Answer (score 0):

Because I am unable to comment as yet, I have some suggestions to clarify the existing answer by mic.

1. No change.
2. No change.
3. The implication in "gets to go" is that the person in that position has the privilege of being first to act. The meaning is closer to "should go" than "may go" or "must go". However, it is important to note that you should take the right of way promptly when it belongs to you.  If you do not, whether due to timidity, fear, or politeness, you create confusion among the other drivers on the road.  If you delay or attempt to allow someone who does not have the right of way to proceed before you, this causes uncertainty and every other driver in the interaction must guess at the best way to proceed.  Practically, this delays everyone and often causes frustration.
4. The entire sentence is poorly constructed. "The car making a right turn at the intersection onto the roadway has the right of way and should proceed before cars turning left onto the roadway."  As mentioned in the previous answer, the original sentence is using "over" in a hierarchical sense.  To be "over" or "above" is the same as being before when used in this way. The opposite would be true for "under" or "beneath".
5. "Variants" is an excellent choice for a substitution in this case. You might also say, "There are many variables that exist in roadway configurations, and the right-of-way rules can, therefore, be convoluted (complicated, or confusing).  The principles discussed above hold (are valid) in most circumstances, and should help you to figure out many different situations." Or, "However many permutations of lane configurations may exist, these right-of-way rules remain valid." Etc.